# Inject DI service into ASP.NET 5 Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm writing a TagHelper for ASP.NET 5 and need to access the file system from within the helper to check if a file exists.

In prior versions I would use the HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath or HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, but these are gone now. What is the equivalent and how do I get at it from within a TagHelper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `[Activate]` attribute to get this service injected into your tag helper.

Example:

```
public class TestTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Initial Name";

    public int Number { get; set; } = 1000;

    [Activate]
    public IApplicationEnvironment ApplicationEnvironment { get; set; }

    public override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath` there's a discution about this on github

> [How do you get current physical path inside Startup.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/405#issuecomment-85469752)

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but I still can't figure out how to get it inside my tag helper. I tried adding it as a constructor parameter, but it wasn't injected by default.

Comment: you can get it at startup an set a property of a singleton may be ?